# How do I replace this string in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter, str-replace

There's this code in my wp theme. I know I'm supposed to simply make/add filters ecc to my child theme functions file...but I don't know php. Here's the code:

```
function astra_get_breadcrumb( $echo = true ) {

    if ( ! $echo ) {
        return '<div class="ast-breadcrumbs-wrapper">
            <div class="ast-breadcrumbs-inner">' .
                astra_get_selected_breadcrumb( $echo ) .
            '</div>
        </div>';
    }

    ?>
    <div class="ast-breadcrumbs-wrapper">
        <div class="ast-breadcrumbs-inner">
            <?php astra_get_selected_breadcrumb( $echo ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

In my theme functions file, I just want to add the class "demo" so that the html ends up being like this in the end
`<div class="ast-breadcrumbs-wrapper demo">`.
As far as I understand, it's a matter of replacing a string, but like I said, I'll only mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
function astra_get_breadcrumb( $echo = true ) {

    if ( ! $echo ) {
        return '<div class="ast-breadcrumbs-wrapper demo">
            <div class="ast-breadcrumbs-inner">' .
                astra_get_selected_breadcrumb( $echo ) .
            '</div>
        </div>';
    }

    ?>
    <div class="ast-breadcrumbs-wrapper demo">
        <div class="ast-breadcrumbs-inner">
            <?php astra_get_selected_breadcrumb( $echo ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```